# Is it possible to track Min/Max In a DynamoDB table with a single query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am making a table to track the minimum and maximum something sold for in a day in a DyanomDB table. I will have a numeric min column and a numeric max column

My goal is

1. If the value I am passing in is between these number, ignore and don't write the table
2. If it is above the max, it is assigned to the max
3. If it is below the min, it is assigned the min
4. If the row does not exist, it is created and the number is assigned to both the min and max.

Is this possible to do in one Update command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one-shot update like you describe is not achievable.  You might think to use [conditional updates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html), but they
cannot manage the *if-this-then-write-here-else-write-there* jujitsu you require.  Here are some DynamoDB patterns you can use<sup>*</sup>:

##### (A) 1 Update, 2 Separate Min/Max Queries

A single update writes individual scores to the table, which has a [compound sort key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html).  Min/max are not persisted, but rather returned at query time. Query `PK = Product1ID and begins_with(SK, "20211218")`.  `Limit=1`.  `ScanIndexForward=False` to return the daily max
product price (DESC order).  `True` returns the daily minimum (ASC order, the default).

```
PK              SK                  SalePrice     Date
Product1ID      20211217#0400        4.00
Product1ID      20211218#0500        5.00
Product1ID      20211218#0600        6.00
Product2ID      20211218#2500       25.00        
Product2ID      20211218#2600       26.00
```

##### (B) 2 Updates, 1 Query

The table has a single record per item per day with the min/max.  Use two conditional updates, one to write the daily max, one for the daily min.  Querying is an easy `PK = Product1ID and SK = "20211218"`.

```
PK              SK                   Min     Max         Date
Product1ID      20211217            4.00    5.50
Product1ID      20211218            5.00    6.00
Product2ID      20211218           25.00   26.00
```

##### (C) 1 Query + 1 Update to Write, 1 Query to Read

A variant on B's 2+1 solution. Same table design and query but different update logic.  At update time, first query the the current product-day record.  The updating function decides what, if any new min/max needs to be written, in a one-shot update.

##### (D) Kitchen Sink

Table has both A's individual and B's min/max records.  Update as in A.  Use [DynamoDB streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/streamsmain.html) to kick off a lambda on
a each new update.  The lambda calculates the max/min and writes back the record to the table.  Query is simple.

```
PK              SK                  SalePrice     Min     Max       Date
Product1ID      20211217                         4.00    5.50
Product1ID      20211217#0400        4.00
Product1ID      20211218                         5.00    6.00
Product1ID      20211218#0500        5.00
Product1ID      20211218#0600        6.00
Product2ID      20211218                        25.00   26.00
Product2ID      20211218#2500       25.00        
Product2ID      20211218#2600       26.00
```

---

* The usual health warnings apply: what patterns are better/worse depends on the use case's [query patterns and data volumes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html#bp-general-nosql-design-approach).  The number of queries/update operations may or may not
be a good measure of efficient design.  Ask your doctor or pharmacist.