# DynamoDB Aggregate Table with MIN and MAX values

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a DynamoDB Table that contains raw data with the following fields

```
id
user_id
total_revenue
timestamp
```

Then I have a Dynamo Stream that pushes the data that changes to a Lambda function which aggregates the data of the batch and produces the results with the following format

```
user_id
sum_total_revenue
min_timestamp
max_timestamp
```

Then I have another DynamoDB Table that I want to update with the aggregated data that the Lambda Function produces.
So there is only one row per user_id with the following attributes

```
sum_total_revenue
min_timestamp
max_timestamp
```

For sum_total_revenue I can perform a update_item function with the following statement

```
{
"TableName" : "agg_table",
"Key":{
                'partition': {"S":"A"}
          },
"UpdateExpression":"SET #attrName = if_not_exists( #attrName, :zero) + :val",
    
"ExpressionAttributeNames" : {
              "#attrName" : "sum_total_revenue"
          },
          "ExpressionAttributeValues":{
            ':val': { "N":"1" },
            ':zero': { "N":"0" },
          },
}
```

But for min and max timestamp I have to perform 2 similar Conditional Updates as a result for every Lambda execution I have to do 3 operations to the DynamoDB table for every user_id in the batch.

Is there another way to implement that in DynamoDB?
Or can I use another service to do that?

Comment: Why not use SQL DB?

Comment: Are `min_timestamp` and `max_timestamp` abitrary begin-end times? Or do your periods of interest [correspond to calendar times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70536353/dynamodb-timeseries-querying-large-timespans-of-data/70541768#70541768) like `2022-01` (Jan 2022) or `2022-01-05T10:00` (5 Jan 2022 10-1100)?

Comment: @fedonev Its the timestamp of the oldest and the newest event. Think about purchases your 1st purchase timestamp and the last purchase timestamp in an e-shop

Comment: Got it, first and last purchase.  [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70401424/is-it-possible-to-track-min-max-in-a-dynamodb-table-with-a-single-query) has a similar "transaction history" use case with entity Min/Max tracking. Four options are covered in (my) answer.  See in particular the last one, a single-table design using Streams.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the number of concurrent writes you expect for any single item.

If you expect high concurrent writes, then your solution is probably the best.

If you don't expect high concurrent writes, you can first fetch the item, figure out if the new min / max timestamps are lower / higher and perform a single update where you set all the values.

This would be cheaper, as you'd have 1 read + 1 write, which is cheaper than 3 reads.

However, you'd still want to use a conditional update, but this time with a version number to implement optimistic locking. So in the unlikely case of a concurrent update, you don't have a lost write problem. In case you get a conflict, you'd need to fetch the item again, and figure out again, what the correct values are. This is why this approach is only beneficial if you do **not** expect many concurrent writes on the same item.